# remove the script in init.d

Tags: init.d

I want to flash TweakDrypT to my rooted android 4.4.2 device. But before, I must delete all the scripts in init.d. I've tried using universal init.d to remove them, but they won't. Anyone can help?

Comment: One urgent hint: Make sure to do a backup first, a *complete* one (see: [nandroid](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/nandroid/info)). That's always the first to do before modifying things in `/system`. 2nd: I don't know why you "must delete all the scripts in init.d" (some background would be helpful; this might well be an [XY problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/66377/192154) ;) But before *removing* them, make sure you have a copy (see: backup). If things go nuts, you might need them again.

Answer (score 1):

Just use any root file manager like [root browser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jrummy.root.browser) and browse to system/etc/init.d and delete all scripts manually

Alternatively, download and install [terminal emulator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm). Open it and enter these commands One by One->

```
su
mount -o rw,remount /system
mkdir /sdcard/init/
cp /system/etc/init.d /sdcard/init/
rm -r /system/etc/init.d/*
```

In first command, we gain the superuser rights. It should request you for root permission, grant it if it does. The second command is to mount the `/system` (partition where init.d scripts reside). And third command creates a new folder "init" in root of internal sdcard (this is where we will backup your scripts in case you will ever need them). The fourth command copies all scripts to folder we created in third step (backup). Fifth command finally removes **all** files inside init.d folder.

Hope this helps.

Comment: and again alternatively, use ADB: `adb shell su -c "mount -o remount,rw /system && cp -a /system/etc/init.d /sdcard && rm -rf /system/etc/init.d/* && mount -o remount,ro / system"`. // Note: do **NOT** use `*.*`, as that would only remove files with a `.` in their name. This is not Windows ;) And don't forget to backup first. Might need that later when things go weird ;)

Comment: Thanks for suggestions, I added the details to answer :)

Comment: And I upvoted it meanwhile. Warning for the missing first step (backup) is in my comments :) // Oops: typo in my first comment to your answer: at the end of the command, there must be NO space between `/` and `system` …